# Default Check not working on angular 2 radio button Form Control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a formcontrol as radio buttons as follow

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Activity Time</label><br/>
     <input type="radio" value="0" (change)="handleActivityTime(false)"   formControlName="activityTime"> By Select
     <input type="radio" value="1" (change)="handleActivityTime(true)"  [checked]="true" formControlName="activityTime"> By Input
 </div>
```

and in my component.ts I create the form control. Here I'm assigning the By Input as the default one and make it as checked. But it is not able to check.

Comment: I tried your code and the default radio button is selected. Could you produce a [mcve] ?

Comment: i show this code on BSModel view and on there it is not showing

Comment: Why you have same formControlName="activityTime" to 2 inputs?

Comment: both are in a same group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is value should be indicate on [value]

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Activity Time</label><br/>
     <input type="radio" value="0" (change)="handleActivityTime(false)"   formControlName="activityTime"> By Select
     <input type="radio" value="1" (change)="handleActivityTime(true)"  [checked]="true" formControlName="activityTime"> By Input
 </div>
```

is working for me. also no need to create formconrol object on the form